# Trying to only allow date picking to be between 45-90 days from today's date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is the code I have so far but I am not sure how to alter this function to also check if the selection was made after 90 days. What I have so far is when you click the date picker, it will jump to 45 days from today and not allow user to choose anything from prior, but the problem is that it will allow past 90 days which is what i dont want.

https://jsfiddle.net/dwyvtajg/

```
    <label id="asterisk">*</label> <label class="description" for="element_2">Event Date:</label><br /><label>Reservations must be made between <b>45-90 days in advance</b> of the event date</label> <br /><input onclick="one()" required="" type="date" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Event-Date" id="datepicker1" min="2019-10-02" />
<script>if ( $('#datepicker1')[0].type != 'date' ) $('#datepicker1').datepicker();</script>


 <script>
    function formatISOLocal(d) {
      let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
      return d.getFullYear()+'-'+z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
    }
    
     function one() {
      let inp = document.querySelector('#datepicker1');
       let d = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(45*24*60*60*1000));
      inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
      inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
      d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() , d.getMonth() + 6);
      inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);
      // Debug
      console.log(inp.outerHTML);
    }
    </script>
```

thanks for the help everyone.... editing this line fixed it!!!
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() , d.getMonth() , d.getDate() +45);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: Not exactly...how would I go about making this work in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take like an hour to review the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate). You're making things so much harder on yourself otherwise.

For instance, setting a min and max date - voila:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        maxDate:'+90d',
        minDate: '+45d',
        onSelect: function(date) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: another good resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-ui-date-picker/

Comment: Hi thank you - when I do this, it still allows for dates to be picked before 45 and after 90??

Comment: oh I think I got it?
    $(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '+45D',
            maxDate: '+90D',
        });
    });

Comment: I think this line here is what is setting the max date allowed to be picked... but not sure how to configure this to be 90 days instead of 6 months

Comment: d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() , d.getMonth() + 6);

Comment: `d.getMonth() + 6` is adding 6 to the `getMonth` method. Change that to `3` and it will add 3 months (~90 days).

Comment: also, your fiddle isn't even importing jquery or jquery-ui, so it's never going to work with your current setup. Here is a fiddle actually importing the necessary scripts and using the datepicker as outlined above https://jsfiddle.net/humanman555/r63otygc/2/